# How did Shimada Die?

Tags: death-parade

He was shown killing Tatsumi, the detective, then the flashback was over.

[image]

Nowhere in the anime did it show how **he** died (and came for judgement). **How did he die?**

Canonical answers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the reddit thread discussing the episode, the same question popped up, to which there was this [reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/2y5rp5/spoilers_death_parade_episode_9_discussion/cp6kqdf):

> [He got stabbed by the guy who assaulted his sister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT5qS.jpg). We saw the latter grab a knife from the kitchen sink and stab him in the hip/back. [You can also see blood staining Shimada's shirt from under his knapsack after he stabs Tatsumi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea2f6.jpg). Actually, he probably could have survived if he didn't overwork himself killing the detective.

Pictures replicated here in order mentioned:

> [image: He got stabbed by the guy who assaulted his sister]
>  [image: You can also see blood staining Shimada's shirt from under his knapsack after he stabs Tatsumi]

So basically, he got stabbed but passed out after killing the detective, then bled to death from his earlier injuries.